# Underlining a \def text

Tags: underline, definition, ulem

So basically I have defined a term:

```
\def\Title{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit risus, maecenas nisl imperdiet aliquet taciti ac.}
```

And I want to underline it, but when I do so it does not break to the next line, but rather shows like this:
[image]

As you can see in the image the "taciti ac." part does not break to the next line.

I used `uline` from the `ulem` package for the above text also but it didn;t work.

The code for the image is:

```
\Title 
\\ 
\uline{\Title}
```

Comment: That's a documented side effect of how `ulem` works. Workaround: `\expandafter\uline\expandafter{\Title}`